# How to make TextView with fading edge?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I have some general programming knowledge, but I am new to android developing, and I have started with `RecyclerView` and I have used `cardview` too. But in some cases the title there is too long and I just want to add a fading edge.

I have searched in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) but I couldn't find anything. So I tried it myself, but I couldn't get it working. I have used it outside the `RecyclerView` too, but still the same result.

The code I am using.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal" <!-- I think those 2 lines should do it,
    android:fadingEdgeLength="40dp"/>
```

I want to make the fading TextView as in this picture from Play Store:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fadingEdge `android:fadingEdge` is deprecated.

It should work with `requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"` and `android:ellipsize="none"` :

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
android:fadingEdgeLength="40dp"
android:ellipsize="none"
```

And I would recommend to use something like `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or `android:layout_width="100dp"` if you like the text to be faded.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. If I use `android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"` it gives me nothing, but if I use it with `android:singleLine="True"` then it gives me three dots (...) at the end of the textView

Comment: Don't forget android:ellipsize="none"

Comment: I was trying it myself with `android:ellipsize="marquee"` , but anyways it works fine now !! Thank you !!

Comment: @gus42 This is not working, I'm trying on OnePLus Device OS version 6.0.1. Any Suggestion !!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, @Эвансгелист Evansgelist's answer worked perfectly, although the fading was a little too subtle (for that particular project).

In the end, I had to add `android:singleLine="true"` to @gus27's answer to make it work and get the effect I wanted:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
android:fadingEdgeLength="40dp"
android:ellipsize="none"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

android 6.0.1

This code works

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="0"
android:singleLine="true"
```

and don't forget

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```